# Javax.enterprise.context.SessionsScoped behaving like Singleton in SpringContainer with JSF as frontend

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I've Web App with front End JSF/RichFaces, Middle Tier Spring and Hibernate for DB. When I deployed the app and accessed from my system and my friends access, My friend could continue whatever the operation I had done(object was behaving as singleton/ applicationcontext). Below is the code of my session  class, web.xml, faces-config.xml and spring.xml. I guess due to same reason I believe viewscoped bean is also not behaving to my expectation. Could somebody help in this case.

```
package org.kp.business;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class OliHolder implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<String, ArrayList<OliData>> oliTypesHolder = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<OliData>>();


    public void addOli(String oliType) {
        OliData oliDetails = new OliData();
        oliDetails.setOliName(oliType);
        oliDetails.initData(oliType);
        ArrayList<OliData> tempHolder = null;
        if(!oliTypesHolder.containsKey(oliType))
        {
            tempHolder = new ArrayList<OliData>();
            tempHolder.add(oliDetails);
            oliTypesHolder.put(oliType, tempHolder);
        }else{
            tempHolder = oliTypesHolder.get(oliType);
            tempHolder.add(oliDetails);
        }
    }

    public void deleOli(int num, String oliType) {
        ArrayList<OliData> list = oliTypesHolder.get(oliType);
        if(null != list && list.size() > 0){
            if((list.size()>num)){  
                list.remove(num);
            }
        }
    }

    public void resetOliHolder(){
        oliTypesHolder.clear();
    }

    public List<OliData> getOlisByType(String oliType){
        ArrayList<OliData> tempHolder = oliTypesHolder.get(oliType);
        return tempHolder;
    }

    public void resetCurrentType(String selectedOli) {
         oliTypesHolder.remove(selectedOli);
    }

    public Map<String, ArrayList<OliData>> getOliTypesHolder() {
        return oliTypesHolder;
    }

}
```

Face-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>EBMMaker</display-name>
    <!-- <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> </welcome-file-list> -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>ruby</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringConfig.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

Spring.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="org.kp"></context:component-scan>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebm" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="root" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="örg.kp.db.model" />
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>
                    classpath:/org/kp/db/hibernate.cfg.xml
                </value>
            </property>
        </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is one class were I'm trying to acess bbOli Bean which is used to get data from database Since I'm creating manually the object, I'm acessing bbOli Bean using application context. I'm not sure the Scope of the OLIData object.

```
package org.kp.business;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.kp.db.model.TblEBMFieldDetails;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

public class OliData {

    BusinessOli bbOli;

    private String oliName;

    public OliData() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext((ServletContext) FacesContext
                        .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext());
        bbOli = (BusinessOli) ctx.getBean("bbOli");
    }

    private String commentText;


    public String getCommentText() {
        return commentText;
    }

    public void setCommentText(String commentText) {
        this.commentText = commentText;
    }

    public String getOliName() {
        return oliName;
    }

    public void setOliName(String oliName) {
        this.oliName = oliName;
    }

    private List<TblEBMFieldDetails> dbEBMData;
    private List<EBMDataForView> renderEBMData;

    public List<EBMDataForView> getRenderEBMData() {
        return renderEBMData;
    }

    public void setRenderEBMData(List<EBMDataForView> renderEBMData) {
        this.renderEBMData = renderEBMData;
    }

    public List<TblEBMFieldDetails> getDbEBMData() {
        return dbEBMData;
    }

    public void setDbEBMData(List<TblEBMFieldDetails> dbEBMData) {
        this.dbEBMData = dbEBMData;
    }

    public void initData(String oliName) {
        this.dbEBMData = bbOli.getOliTypeSpfcData(oliName);
        renderEBMData = new ArrayList<EBMDataForView>();
        for (TblEBMFieldDetails dt : dbEBMData) {
            EBMDataForView data = new EBMDataForView();
            data.setCmplxFlg(dt.isCollectionFlg());
            if (dt.isCollectionFlg() && null != dt.getValues()) {
                data.setFieldCollectionValue(dt.getValues().split(","));
                System.out.println("Hey I'm: "+data.getFieldCollectionValue().length);
            }

            data.setFieldDefaultValue(dt.getDefaultValue());
            data.setFieldName(dt.getFieldName());
            data.setRequiredFld(dt.isReqFlg());
            renderEBMData.add(data);
        }
    }

}
```

After Change

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@ManagedBean(name = "bbOliHolder")
@ViewScoped
public class OliHolderBacking implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String selectedTab;

    @Autowired
    BusinessOli bbOli;

    public BusinessOli getBbOli() {
        return bbOli;
    }


    public void setBbOli(BusinessOli bbOli) {
        this.bbOli = bbOli;
    }

    @Autowired
    OliHolder oliHolder;

    private String[] allOliTypes = null;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        allOliTypes = getBbOli().getAllOlisFromDB();
        olis = new ArrayList<OliData>();
    }

}
```

Service Layer Bean

```
import java.util.List;

import org.kp.db.dao.EBMDetailDao;
import org.kp.db.dao.impl.OlisImpl;
import org.kp.db.model.TblEBMFieldDetails;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("bbOli")
@Scope("prototype")
public class BusinessOli{

    @Autowired
    OlisImpl olisImpl;

    @Autowired
    EBMDetailDao ebmData;

    public String[] getAllOlisFromDB() {

        String[] str = olisImpl.getAllOlis();
        return str;
    }
}
```

However The Autowiring in BusinessOli were working earlier before the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Spring doesn't support CDI annotations introduced in Java EE 6 (JSR 299), so you should use spring annotation to define scope of your bean, in your case that would be:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Scope("session")
```

In your case Spring used default scope, which is indeed Singleton.

Comment: Then I've another bean, which has JSF scope viewScoped, what would be its scope? will Spring allow JSF scope to be handled by JSF Container?

Comment: If you use `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` and `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` Spring will not handle these beans at all. They will be created just by JSF Spring doesn't manage JSF annotations. Actually in mu projects for backing beans I just use JSF annotation and JSF managed beans for backing beans. For services and core classes I use spring managed beans.

Comment: As you had suggested, I had segregated JSF Bean and Spring Bean however, Its failing while I'm trying to Autowire the bean inside the Bean OliHolderBackingBean, however before change I was Auotwireing the bean in bbOli which was working fine

Comment: When you have JSF managed bean use ManagedProperty annotation to inject property. Define getters and setters as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did the samething what you mentioned everything works as per my expectation, Thanks alot again

Comment: Hi @partlov, I've question if I decalre a Bean as ManagedBean and scope as ViewScoped will it work or will it have problem as mentioned by infragile

Comment: That is one of reasons why I use JSF managed beans for backing beans and not Spring. `@ViewScope` is buil in JSF and that is not a problem. In fact `@ViewScoped` is most used scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring and JSF together it's beneficial to use Spring beans instead of JSF Managed beans. Spring beans offer almost all functionality of JSF managed beans and on top of that adds sooo many useful Spring features (AOP, proxies, weaving, MessageSources etc.).

If you decide to use Spring beans you have to use Spring Scopes as listed in `WebApplicationContext`:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
```

**VIEW SCOPE**

There is one catch. As you can see there is no `SCOPE_VIEW` in `WebApplicationContext`.
JSF 2 View scope is not yet supported in Spring. 
For now you have to provide your own implementation of view scope. It's not difficult:

- You can find **instructions** here:
  https://github.com/weijiguang/OA/wiki/Spring-3-and-the-JSF-2-View-Scope(spring-2%E5%8F%8AJSF-2-bean%E4%BD%9C%E7%94%A8%E5%9F%9F)
- You can also find **working implementation** here:
  https://github.com/michail-nikolaev/primefaces-spring-scopes
- And don't forget to vote for **JSF 2 View scope support in Spring**
  here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6543